# Parse JSON object with variable keys

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

I have to parse JSON objects which contains two keys which can be different in each object. In the example below it is the `"path/to/file"` and the accession `"ecs2345.ms067"`.

I need to inspect both objects and evaluate the value of `"ok"` and `"version"`.
All examples I found expect a defined key.

Parser is Python or Postgres jsonb. I am particularly interested if it is possible to use JSON path.

Thanks!

```
{
    "path/to/file": [
        {
            "ecs2345.ms067": {
                "error_type": "__prevalidation__",
                "errors": [
                    "missing : origin_sample_ontology_curie"
                ],
                "ok": false,
                "version": "2.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "ecs2345.ms067": {
                "errors": [],
                "ok": true,
                "version": "1.0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json.loads` to convert the whole thing to a dictionary and then iterate through the dictionary:

```py
json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
for filename, file_data in json_dict.items():
    for obj in file_data:
        ok = obj["ok"]
        version = obj["version"]
        # do stuff with the variables.
        # if you need the file name, it is filename variable.
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you know if it is possible to use JSON Path?

Comment: ``$[*][*]['ecs2345.ms067']['ok']`` and ``$[*][*]['ecs2345.ms067']['version']`` will return one it per file and object in the file collection

Comment: Perfect, thanks. All new territory for me, this really helps.